# Multiprocessing doesn't call function in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a function that I want to call with multiprocessing but it doesn't work at all.
I can't find any solutions to that problem. Here is my code.

```
import numpy as np
import time as tm
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Process

def LU():
   
    A=np.zeros((n,n))
    L=np.zeros((n,n))
    U=np.zeros((n,n))
    for r in range(n):
        for c in range(n):
            A[r,c]=input('element α['+str(r+1)+','+str(c+1)+']=')
            A[r,c]=float(A[r,c])
            U[r,c]=A[r,c]
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if i==j:
                L[i,j]=1
            if i<j:
                ratio=A[j,i]/A[i,i]
                L[j,i]=ratio
                for k in range(n):
                    A[j,k]=A[j,k]-(ratio*A[i,k])
                    U[j,k]=A[j,k]
    print('L=',L,'\n','U=',U)
   
#main program
n=int(input('Give matrix dimentions:'))
p = Process(target=LU)
p.start()
p.join()
```

Comment: Hi @GeorgeP, could you add some info about how this isn't working - what output are you getting and what do you expect?

Comment: It asks for the dimentions and then the program is finished. There is no error but the function never gets called

Comment: Is that a [mcve]? What if you remove the whole computation and input and only call `print()` inside `LU()`? Further, I'm not sure whether output from a subprocess is automatically echoed where output from the parent process is echoed. Check the documentation. That said, it might be just for the example, but starting and immediately joining a process doesn't make much sense, I assume you're aware of that.

Comment: If you can make it even simpler, it is _not_ minimal. That's the point of it, reduce it to represent the core of the problem, not any irrelevant stuff on the side! Also, [edit] your question, don't just put that into comments here.

Comment: What platform are you running on (Windows? Linux?). Are you running in any special environment, such as Jupyter Notebook, or from a command prompt?

Comment: I think found the problem. I was running the code with IDLE but with VS Code it works fine.